Azure SQL: hierarchyid performance issues
(Apologies for the lengthy post - first post on SE)
I've been using the hierarchyid type in various applications for about 10 years now and I've been generally happy with the performance. I occasionally came across reports of poor performance with hierarchyid and always assumed it was due to incorrectly configured indexes or queries that could be optimized. But now I ran into the issue myself.
Azure SQL, database compatibility level set to 160 (SQL Server 2022).
I have the following table:
create table [Dim]
(
    [Key] [int] not null,
    [Path] [hierarchyid] null,
    [Name] [nvarchar](256) null,
    [ParentKey] [int] null,
    [SortOrder] [int] null,
    [IsLeaf] [bit] null,
    constraint PK_Dim primary key clustered ([Key]),
    index IX_Dim_Name unique ([Name]) include ([Path]),
    index IX_Dim_ParentKey unique ([ParentKey], [SortOrder]),
    index IX_Dim_Path ([Path]),
    index IX_Dim_Leaf ([IsLeaf], [Path])
)

The table is designed to model a parent-child hierarchy. The Path field reflects the hierarchy, based on the parent Path and the SortOrder of the current member. There are 10,010 records in the test data set with a maximum hierarchy depth of 8. We run the following query:
select d.[Key], r.[SortOrder], r.[Key], r.[Name], r.[Level]
from (
    select row_number() over (order by d.[Path]) as [SortOrder], d.[Key], d.[Name], d.[Path].GetLevel() as [Level], d.[Path]
    from [Dim] d
    inner join [Dim] p on (d.[Path].IsDescendantOf(p.[Path]) = 1)
    where p.[Name] = 'A8'
) r
inner join [Dim] d on (d.[Path].IsDescendantOf(r.[Path]) = 1
        and d.[IsLeaf] = 1);

The query takes 14 seconds to execute and returns 3,053 rows. Subquery returns 1,298 rows.
Below is the execution plan:

and a link: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=SydK3qIk1l
which looks pretty much what I expected, with the exception of the index scan on IX_Dim_Leaf, which reads 6,861,228 rows.

Now, if add an additional column to the table which contains the string representation of the Path field and the corresponding two indexes on the new field:
alter table [Dim] add [PathStr] varchar(256);
go
update [Dim] set [PathStr] = [Path].ToString();
create index [IX_Dim_PathStr] on [Dim] ([PathStr]);
create index [IX_Dim_LeafStr] on [Dim] ([IsLeaf], [PathStr]);
go

and then rewrite the query to use PathStr instead of Path:
select d.[Key], r.[SortOrder], r.[Key], r.[Name], r.[Level]
from (
    select row_number() over (order by d.[PathStr]) as [SortOrder], d.[Key], d.[Name], d.[Path].GetLevel() as [Level], d.[PathStr]
    from [Dim] d
    inner join [Dim] p on (d.[PathStr] like p.[PathStr] + '%')
    where p.[Name] = 'A8'
) r
inner join [Dim] d on (d.[PathStr] like r.[PathStr] + '%'
    and d.[IsLeaf] = 1);

The new query executes in 0.064 seconds. Execution plan is below:

and the link: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=Sy5oT5Uyye
It's actually more complex than the first query plan due to the new field not being included in the IX_Dim_Name index and having to add the '%' string, but the big difference is in the outer index scan, where only 3053 rows are read instead of 6.8 mil.

It does not make any sense to me for a string field to perform better than a hierarchyid field which theoretically is optimized for this kind of hierarchical queries. Am I doing something wrong or is SQL Server simply unable to deal with hierarchyids in subqueries and we should stick with a string field?
Note: Storing the results of the subquery in a table var and then joining the table var with the Dim table actually performs marginally better when using hierarchyid, but unfortunately that is not an option.
Edit: at Charlieface's suggestion below I also tried this query:
select d.[Key], r.[SortOrder], r.[Key], r.[Name], r.[Level]
from (
    select row_number() over (order by d.[Path]) as [SortOrder], d.[Key], d.[Name], d.[Path].GetLevel() as [Level], d.[Path]
    from [Dim] d
    inner join [Dim] p on (d.[Path].IsDescendantOf(p.[Path]) = 1)
    where p.[Name] = 'A8'
) r
inner join [Dim] d on (d.[Path].GetAncestor(1) = r.[Path]
        and d.[IsLeaf] = 1);

which executes in 38 ms (plan execution). It seems only IsDescendantOf() is a problem.

The problem, as you have noted, is that the Index Seek isn't really a seek. It returns every row that has IsLeaf=1, which is a very large part of the table.
It seems IsDescendantOf is not using an optimized access path. I found the only way to get this to work properly is to remove the derived table (subquery) and replace row_number with dense_rank.
select
  d2.[Key],
  row_number() over (order by d.Path) AS SortOrder,
  d.[Key],
  d.Name,
  d.Path.GetLevel() as Level
from Dim d
inner join Dim p on d.Path.IsDescendantOf(p.Path) = 1
inner join Dim d2 on d2.Path.IsDescendantOf(d.Path) = 1
        and d2.IsLeaf = 1
where p.Name = 'A8';


Why this is happening, I'm not sure, as it seems fairly trivial for the optimizer to work this out. The row_number does not affect this, I had the same result even after removing as well as the GetLevel() call. I suspect there may be a bug in the optimizer here.

One workaround I found if you still want to use a derived table or CTE, was to instead use GetAncestor(1) to get the immediate parent. That seems to still have an optimized path.
select
  d.[Key],
  r.SortOrder,
  r.[Key],
  r.Name,
  r.Level
from (
    select
      row_number() over (order by d.Path) as SortOrder,
      d.[Key],
      d.Name,
      d.Path.GetLevel() as Level,
      d.Path
    from Dim d
    inner join Dim p on d.Path.GetAncestor(1) = p.Path
    where p.Name = 'A8'
) r
inner join Dim d on d.Path.GetAncestor(1) = r.Path
        and d.IsLeaf = 1;


One further point: you still ended up with a Key Lookup. You can avoid this by adding Name to the IX_Dim_Path index.
    index IX_Dim_Path ([Path]) include (Name),

db<>fiddle

Thank you, this makes a lot of sense! Looks like I'll keep using the string field for descendant queries and the hierarchyid for ancestor queries -- the additional storage requirements are minimal. Also, thanks for the hint about IX_Dim_Path!
